# Remove AllUsers from ACL policy in bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jq

I have a response from aws like this

```
{
  "Owner": {
    "DisplayName": "2414218.aws",
    "ID": "xxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Grants": [
    {
      "Grantee": {
        "DisplayName": "2414218.aws",
        "ID": "yyyyyyyyyy"
      },
      "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
    },
    {
      "Grantee": {
        "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
      },
      "Permission": "READ"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking to update the files so AllUsers is removed (get-object-acl should look like the below)

```
{
  "Owner": {
    "DisplayName": "2414218.aws",
    "ID": "xxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Grants": [
    {
      "Grantee": {
        "DisplayName": "2414218.aws",
        "ID": "yyyyyyyyyy"
      },
      "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I do this, not knowing what other grantees are available? I am specifically looking to remove a grantee when I see `http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers`

I am currently using `aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket mhe-deployments-prod --key $keyFile | jq '.'` to locate the policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jq filter which will remove all the .Grants array elements for which .Grantee.URI is "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers":

```
.Grants |= map( select(.Grantee.URI != "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers") )
```

Output: as requested

Answer (score 2):

You can do using the built in `--query` option in the AWS CLI.  The benefit being you don't need any external tools:

```
 aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket $BUCKET --key $KEY  \
   --query "{Owner: Owners, \
             Grants: Grants[?Grantee.URI != 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers']}"
```

Comment: Nice one, that was pretty much what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best but, this worked

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# aws ~/.aws/credentials and s3cmd must be configured first with proper creds

target=''
for key in $(aws s3 ls s3://$target --recursive |awk '{print$4}') ; do
  [ "${key: -1}" == "/" ] || {
    award=$(aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket $target --key $key |jq '.Grants[].Grantee | .URI' |grep -v 'null' |grep AllUsers)

    [ ! -z "${award}" ] && {
      policy=$(aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket $target --key $key)
      echo "$target: $key\n$policy\n\n" >> /tmp/policy-backup.json
      echo -e "Working on: $key"

      s3cmd setacl s3://$target/$key --acl-private  ## s3cmd must be comfigured to your env
    }
  }
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In this problem the specified grant can also be removed directly with `del`. e.g

```
del(
    .Grants[]
  | select(.Grantee.URI == "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers")
)
```